# Installing python deps with pip -r requirements.txt fails, but installing one by one succeeds. Why?

Tags: python, pip, opencl

I have the following `requirements.txt` file:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
decorator==4.3.0
numpy==1.15.4
pybind11==2.2.4
pyopencl==2018.2.2
pytools==2018.5.2
six==1.12.0
```

Running `pip install -r requirements.txt` fails with:

```
Collecting appdirs==1.4.3 (from -r reqs.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/eb/810e700ed1349edde4cbdc1b2a21e28cdf115f9faf263f6bbf8447c1abf3/appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator==4.3.0 (from -r reqs.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/bb/a24838832ba35baf52f32ab1a49b906b5f82fb7c76b2f6a7e35e140bac30/decorator-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy==1.15.4 (from -r reqs.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/04/bd774106ae0ae1ada68c67efe89f1a16b2aa373cc2db15d974002a9f136d/numpy-1.15.4-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.8MB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting pybind11==2.2.4 (from -r reqs.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/7c/e71995e59e108799800cb0fce6c4b4927914d7eada0723dd20bae3b51786/pybind11-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting pyopencl==2018.2.2 (from -r reqs.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/58/3ab1246e94986f1b6953e76d7ea7e69d2dbfef7b3f3874eded48524a024f/pyopencl-2018.2.2.tar.gz (341kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 348kB 1.1MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Pybind11 is not installed.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Very likely, the build process after this message will fail.

    Simply press Ctrl+C and type
    python -m pip install pybind11
    to fix this. If you don't, the build will continue
    in a few seconds.

    [1] https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Continuing in 1 seconds...    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Mako is not installed.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    That is not a problem, as most of PyOpenCL will be just fine
    without it. Some higher-level parts of pyopencl (such as
    pyopencl.reduction) will not function without the templating engine
    Mako [1] being installed. If you would like this functionality to
    work, you might want to install Mako after you finish
    installing PyOpenCL.

    Simply type
    python -m pip install mako
    either now or after the installation completes to fix this.

    [1] http://www.makotemplates.org/
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Hit Ctrl-C now if you'd like to think about the situation.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Continuing in 1 seconds...   
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-d25rz2_5/pyopencl/setup.py", line 353, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-d25rz2_5/pyopencl/setup.py", line 320, in main
        language='c++',
      File "/tmp/pip-install-d25rz2_5/pyopencl/aksetup_helper.py", line 41, in __init__
        self._include_dirs = self.include_dirs
      File "/tmp/pip-install-d25rz2_5/pyopencl/aksetup_helper.py", line 55, in get_include_dirs
        return self._include_dirs + self.get_additional_include_dirs()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-d25rz2_5/pyopencl/aksetup_helper.py", line 52, in get_additional_include_dirs
        return [self.get_numpy_incpath()]
      File "/tmp/pip-install-d25rz2_5/pyopencl/aksetup_helper.py", line 47, in get_numpy_incpath
        file, pathname, descr = find_module("numpy")
      File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 296, in find_module
        raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
    ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-d25rz2_5/pyopencl/
```

Whereas running:

```
pip install numpy==1.15.4
pip install pybind11==2.2.4
pip install pyopencl==2018.2.2
```

works like a charm. Any idea why?
Thanks in advance.

**--------- EDIT: ---------**

I have also tried with `pip-tools` without success... In this case I created a file `requirements.in`:

```
numpy
pybind11
pyopencl
```

And ran `pip-compile`, which fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/.venv/bin/pip-compile", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/piptools/scripts/compile.py", line 196, in cli
    results = resolver.resolve(max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/piptools/resolver.py", line 101, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/piptools/resolver.py", line 198, in _resolve_one_round
    for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/piptools/resolver.py", line 284, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 217, in get_dependencies
    self._dependencies_cache[ireq] = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 183, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 298, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 126, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.run_egg_info()
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 473, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmp0ykgmwk4build/pyopencl/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Running `pip install -r requirements.txt` fails ... Whereas running:
>
> ```
> pip install numpy==1.15.4
> pip install pybind11==2.2.4
> pip install pyopencl==2018.2.2
> ```
>
> works like a charm. Any idea why?

That's because the two commands are not identical. `pip install` supports multiple arguments (installing multiple packages in one pass), so the command equivalent to `pip install -r requirements.txt` would rather be

```
$ pip install numpy==1.15.4 pybind11==2.2.4 pyopencl==2018.2.2  # etc
```

and this one will fail. The reason for this is that `pyopencl` contains not only Python code, but also C code (so-called "C extension") that needs to be compiled with a C compiler before it can be installed. For the compilation, both `numpy` and `pybind11` must already be installed when `pyopencl` starts building the extensions, but they are only scheduled for installation at that time. Thus, `pip` is unable to build `pyopencl`, thus can't prepare it for installation and in the end, fails the whole command, installing nothing at all.

This is unfortunately quite a common issue. There are two ways to avoid it:

1. Basically, this is the same approach as the one you've already discovered: install different groups of packages in separate `pip install` commands. Split the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command into two: create `requirements-pre.txt` (name is not relevant). Move `numpy` and `pybind11` from `requirements.txt` to `requirements-pre.txt`. Now install the packages with

   ```
   $ pip install -r requirements-pre.txt && pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
2. Use [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and Pipfiles instead of `pip` and "requirements" text files, as `pipenv` knows how to reinstall failed dependencies in a single pass. Packages persisted in the Pipfile

   ```
   [[source]]
   url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
   verify_ssl = true

   [packages]
   numpy = "==1.15.4"
   pybind11 = "==2.2.4"
   pyopencl = "==2018.2.2"
   ```

can be installed with a single `pipenv install` command.

> And ran `pip-compile`, which fails with:

This is the same error as with `pip install`, only that the original traceback is hidden by `pip-compile`.

Comment: hoefling: When you say "The reason for this is that *pybind11* contains not only Python code, but also C code (so-called "C extension") that needs to be compiled with a C compiler before it can be installed." I believe you meant *pyopencl*, since pybind11 is a C++ template library, no compilation is done when installing it.

Comment: Also, if I try to install scipy only with pip, `pip install scipy`, it will detect that numpy is not installed and install it.

Comment: @GLabs you're right, my bad - meant `pyopencl` of course. As for `scipy`, it would cause no problem when installing by default because it offers wheels for most platforms where the stuff is already precompiled. If you install it explicitly from source dist on a system without `numpy`, you should get the same problem in the end. Should be reproducible with e.g. `pip uninstall -y numpy scipy && pip install numpy scipy --no-binary=scipy`.